# How to diagnose intermittent freezing?

Tags: freeze

My Ubuntu box has begun to freeze intermittently, and I want to understand how I can start to diagnose and troubleshoot this?

[image]

- The machine is acting as a server, sitting in my garage, hosting a small number of web applications through Docker.
- Every once in a while, the machine becomes totally unresponsive. It does not answer web requests, and I cannot even access it by SSH. After ten minutes or so, everything is fine again.
- When I then log into the machine via SSH, I can see by the `top` command that something is bogging it down *hard:* the **normal load is <0.5** but sometimes, *something* is pushing it **over 170!** No wonder it looks to be frozen!

**Update:**

`dmesg -T | grep ill` shows that one of the Docker containers was recently killed by the system, and the same happened yesterday. That would coincide with the time when the machine became responsive again.
`cat /var/log/syslog` did not have entries around this tiestamp.

Evidently there is a  problem with a process named `mattermost`. This is where I must investigate further.

```
[Do Mär  2 12:18:39 2023] [   3858]  1000  3858   113617      243   106496        5             0 gsd-rfkill
[Do Mär  2 12:18:39 2023] oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=/,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/docker/4fef02a344354214b6acb6f36102bc59e9dc50557d5c2632d70ab3daac100a5f,task=bundle,pid=1538755,uid=998
[Do Mär  2 12:18:39 2023] Out of memory: Killed process 1538755 (bundle) total-vm:1578372kB, anon-rss:904568kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:1956kB, UID:998 pgtables:2900kB oom_score_adj:0
[Do Mär  2 12:19:23 2023] nxnode.bin invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x1100cca(GFP_HIGHUSER_MOVABLE), order=0, oom_score_adj=0
[Do Mär  2 12:19:23 2023]  oom_kill_process.cold+0xb/0x10
[Do Mär  2 12:19:23 2023] [   3858]  1000  3858   113617      243   106496        5             0 gsd-rfkill
[Do Mär  2 12:19:23 2023] oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=/,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/docker/83ee973eca02114fae81d46c67fd021c6fad40eb124609eff8f6067ff22335dc,task=mattermost,pid=3800325,uid=2000
[Do Mär  2 12:19:23 2023] Out of memory: Killed process 3800325 (mattermost) total-vm:25852356kB, anon-rss:4436936kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:2000 pgtables:9268kB oom_score_adj:0
[Fr Mär  3 10:31:08 2023] systemd invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x1100cca(GFP_HIGHUSER_MOVABLE), order=0, oom_score_adj=0
[Fr Mär  3 10:31:08 2023]  oom_kill_process.cold+0xb/0x10
[Fr Mär  3 10:31:08 2023] [   3858]  1000  3858   113617      245   106496        5             0 gsd-rfkill
[Fr Mär  3 10:31:08 2023] oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=/,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/docker/6ceafe411e36e8c1ceb396ae0fe9e0772399b4d981f0c3b9f108c4b637300d6f,task=bundle,pid=2216864,uid=998
[Fr Mär  3 10:31:08 2023] Out of memory: Killed process 2216864 (bundle) total-vm:1627016kB, anon-rss:922008kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:1956kB, UID:998 pgtables:2932kB oom_score_adj:0
[Fr Mär  3 10:31:46 2023] nxnode.bin invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x1100cca(GFP_HIGHUSER_MOVABLE), order=0, oom_score_adj=0
[Fr Mär  3 10:31:46 2023]  oom_kill_process.cold+0xb/0x10
[Fr Mär  3 10:31:46 2023] [   3858]  1000  3858   113617      245   106496        5             0 gsd-rfkill
[Fr Mär  3 10:31:46 2023] oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=/,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/docker/66ecc2904f86807abf8e5a3e5fb9310028a03c19d09f6b8973eb2c6801c943f7,task=mattermost,pid=2425866,uid=2000
[Fr Mär  3 10:31:46 2023] Out of memory: Killed process 2425866 (mattermost) total-vm:101008668kB, anon-rss:4685940kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:2000 pgtables:10188kB oom_score_adj:0
```

Comment: Maybe include what's happening in the `syslog` or `dmesg` around the times when it becomes unresponsive?

Comment: Mange tak, @ArturMeinild - that was a helpful question that led me to find a memory-eating process. *Why* that happens is a different topic!

Comment: Sure - at least the invocation of `oom-kill` explains why the system becomes unresponsive.